# Top bar is eating my title bars

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

I'm trying not to hate Unity, but I'm still not in love.

If I have windows non-maximized, I often find that the window is stuck so the title bar is hidden by my Unity top bar. I had to enable Compiz's Window Management Grid just to give myself ctrl-alt-num6 as a way to force windows back into the visible screen.

Is there a way to keep windows from slipping up under the top bar?

Comment: While not an answer, you can hold ALT and left-click (and hold) anywhere in a window to move it around. From there you have your window controls accessible again.

Comment: Yup. I do a lot of that as well.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: No, I installed OpenBox. I never could get Unity to work for me.

Comment: @Amanda I ran into this problem in Compiz the other day (using Gnome-classic) and I found the solution. I'll post an answer, since it may help someone else.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 and the same problem, but this didn't solve it with many apps - SciTE is the most noteable. Is there any way to force programs to NEVER be able to go under the taskbar? This is really annoying to have to ALT+CLICK to even close a window or to move it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate option in the Compiz Place Windows plugin.

- Open CCSM (make sure you have it installed first).
- Find the Place Windows plugin:
  [image: CSSM]
- Now, in the options, make sure that smart placement is selected.
  [image: Smarty]

This option is usually set by default, but sometimes for some reason it is not. I am not 100% certain as to the cause (still trying to find it). If you do not have the place windows plugin, make sure to check that you have any additional compiz plugins installed in the software center.

Comment: For me, it is Smart already, and yet my title bar is behind top bar... Alt+drag worked for me though. Perhaps it was an unintentional Alt+drag that got me there at the first place.

Comment: In my computer placement mode is already set to smart, but I have this problem too.

Comment: works for me on 15.10 (wily) -- I had Place Windows disabled.